# Specialize C++ class template with final specifier

Tags: c++, template-specialization, visual-c++-2012

I have a template and a specialization defined like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct SomeTemplate final
{
};

template<>
struct SomeTemplate<int> final
{
};

int main()
{
    SomeTemplate<int> test; // <-- error
}
```

Compiling with Visual C++ 2012 gives me the following error:

```
error C2913: explicit specialization; 'SomeTemplate<T>' is not a specialization of a class template
    with
    [
        T=int
    ]
```

It compiles fine and does the right thing when I remove

- the `final` specifiers
- the `template<>` from the specialization

The first case makes some sense to me, as it may very well be that `final` does also restrict specialization of templates (instead of only inheritance). The second case seems a bit strange to me, as I thought this should be a syntax error.

Is this behavior correct?

Comment: FYI, this builds fine with g++ 4.8.5.

Comment: Are you sure VS2012 handles `final`?

Comment: @YSC According to Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx) and what the compiler says, yes

Comment: If you drop the `final` in the definition of `SomeTemplate<int>`, can you inherit from it? Does VS let you define `struct Test : SomeTemplate<int> {};`?

Comment: You should submit a bug report to MS. This is perfectly legal code.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Not sure MS would even consider fixing bugs in VS2012 instead of saying that one should use VS2015. In other words, not sure how long MS offers support for older compilers.

Comment: @MarcelMarré, does it work in VS2015?

Comment: @MarcelMarré According to [MS Support Lifecycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&qid=&alpha=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Professional%202012&Filter=FilterNO) it should be supported at least until 2018.

Comment: Sadly, Microsoft makes it really hard to report a bug. After clicking around on some pages for a while, I give up. I can work around that particular bug and will probably not have to use VS2012 in the near future anymore. If someone else knows how to report a bug, please feel free to do so.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Sorry, I don't actually use VS myself (otherwise I might have known about the actual support lifecycle that Simon Lehmann mentions), so I don't know. It was just a "theoretical worry".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure weather it's a bug of Visual C++ 2012, your original code compiles fine with the newer version of VC++ [here](http://rextester.com/IWO40798).

> 1. as it may very well be that final does also restrict specialization of templates (instead of only inheritance)

No, [final specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) has nothing to do with template specialization.

> Specifies that a virtual function cannot be overridden in a derived class or that a class cannot be inherited from.

And

> 2. The second case seems a bit strange to me, as I thought this should be a syntax error.

Yes it should be a syntax [error](http://rextester.com/ZLDV15656) if you remove `template<>`.